# Prevent workspaces-enabled pnpm from manipulating stdout?

Tags: pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I decided to try using workspaces in my multi-package repo, managed by pnpm. But I quickly ran into a problem when running `pnpm install`:

```
. postinstall$ <COMMANDS HERE>
[20 lines collapsed]
│ ../.. postinstall: <CUSTOM OUTPUT HERE>
<...>
│ ../.. postinstall: <CUSTOM OUTPUT CONTINUED HERE>
└─ Running...
```

I have custom postinstall scripts that apply color to stdout and manipulate the cursor position to display progress on certain tasks. This works fine with `pnpm i` if workspaces are disabled (i.e., if pnpm-workspace.yaml is absent).

But with workspaces, pnpm tries to apply some fancy cursor-manipulation and formatting of its own, and it results in completely garbage output from my custom scripts. How can I prevent pnpm from doing this?

I've tried all `--reporter` options to no luck, and `--reporter-hide-prefix` appears to be only for `pnpm run`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways.

You can use [--aggregate-output](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#--aggregate-output), in that case the output will be aggregated in memory and printed once when the child process finishes.

You can use [--stream](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#--stream) and the output will be not grouped just printed immediately.

`--reporter=append-only` should also work. It will probably be similar to the `--stream` output.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, though unfortunately none worked. Looks like this is a longstanding issue with recursive pnpm runs: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/2148 (unresolved since November 2019)